# Passing a custom object to the web service

Tags: web-services

I'm using C# and I have windows form and web service...

I have a custom object that I want to send to the web service..

sometime, the object may contain a huge of data..

as a best performance, what is the best way to send a custom object to the web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Services are designed to handle custom objects as long as they eventually breakdown into some standard types. As per sending a huge data, there are [MTOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTOM) and older [DIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188797.aspx). If it's within LAN and against other .NET client, you might want to look into non-Web Services ways like Remoting or plain http.

See [How to: Enable a Web Service to Send and Receive Large Amounts of Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the link - very useful to know.  Ironically, I almost closed this question a little while ago.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using / plan to use WCF within the network(as opposed to internet), named pipes on WCF is fast and simple. Use primitive types to pass objects. A string xml (although verbose) or a light weight binary object will do.

If it's a wsHttp webservice, use string, I can't think of any other way you would pass a custom object, unless the service knows about it.