# Can I pass a non-primitive data type to a WebMethod?

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-2.0

I am having an issue where I am attempting to pass a non-primitive (and user defined) data type into a WebMethod.  Is there a certain way to do this?  Here is an example of my code:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool GetTableRecordCnt(int i, String str, DateTime? lastUpdatedDate, UserDefinedType udt, out FDT_SCHEDULER_STATUS[] schedulerTable)
{
    //code
}
```

When I try to call this function from my client application I get the following error:

"Unable to read data from the transport connection."

If I replace the UserDefineType parameter with a primitive data type (an int for example) the client is able to get a response from the WebMethod.

Thanks in advance for you help.

EDIT:

Calling code from client application:

```
UserDefinedType udt = new UserDefinedType();
UserDefinedType1[] tableRecords = ThisApplication.FillArray();

bool result = WebServiceReferenceName.GetTableRecordCnt(1, "tableName", "10/10/2010 12:00:00", udt, out tableRecords);
```

That is a gross oversimplification of the parameters that are being passed to the web method, but the data that is in each parameter is what would be passed.

Comment: which platform is your client application using? winforms or asp.net?

Comment: The client application is using winforms for a windows mobile 5.0 device.

Comment: Posted the calling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so finding out what the problem is has finally given me some relief =)

Apparently there is a limit to the number of characters that a variable can be named when you pass a UserDefinedType to a web method.   After testing with each piece that I added for this new function in my code.  I found that shortening the following variable name:

```
SchedulerRecordCount
```

to:

```
SchedRecCnt
```

is now allowing data to be passed between my windows mobile application and the c# web service.  GO FIGURE!

Now, does anyone know if there is a specific numeric limit to the number of characters that can be used to name a variable in a UserDefinedType that will be passed to a Web Method, or could this be an environment issue on my end?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You would need to create an object which matched the public properties of your UserDefinedType. This is fairly simply if you are using .Net webservices and have marked the method as [ScriptMethod()] which will then respond to JSON.

Here's an example:

```
public class UserDefinedType
{
   public int Property1 { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Which you could pass as a param using the following javascript:

```
var param = "{ Property1 : '"+prop1Val+"', Property2 : '"+prop2Val+"'}";
```

Note, you have to declare the JSON object being passed as a string as otherwise if you are using jQuery.ajax(...) it will serialise your param object to an encoded param string rather than pass it as a native JSON string.

There are also some nice libraries out there that will take care of the JSON data object to string for you such as [jquery-json 2.2](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/). Using this you can then simply pass the param as $.toJSON(param).

Finally, here's an example of sending the request to an ASP .Net web service using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Services/YourService.asmx/YourMethod",
        cache: false,
        data: $.toJSON(param), // Convert JSON object to String for Post
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            HandleResponse(response.d)
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('error during web service call');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is of little help.  I am not using JSON and JQUERY for this project.

Comment: @AndHeCodedIt: You weren't clear when you posted your question whether you were using Windows Forms or ASP .Net. With the Windows Form approach you should have a SOAP proxy class setup which enables you to create a proxy object for the user defined type. Just remember that its only the public properties that are mapped back and forth.

Comment: thanks for the information, did not mean to insult you if you are insulted.  I also made it +1 because your answer would be useful in other applications =)

Comment: @AndHeCodedIt: no problem, not insulted :-)

Answer (score 1):

For now I have an answer to my own question.  I have changed the web service method signature to:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool GetTableRecordCnt(int i, String str, DateTime? lastUpdatedDate, object udt, out FDT_SCHEDULER_STATUS[] schedulerTable)
{
    //code
}
```

Notice that I changed the UserDefinedType type to object.  Now I am able to get my client to talk to my web service.  Does anyone have any reason that this should not be done?

Answer (score 1):

This explain your problem: [Passing a custom object to the web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347047/passing-a-custom-object-to-the-web-service)

Probably your UserDefinedType contains "fancy" stuff like List, Dictionary or something that can't be serialized thus you get error.

I'm surprised that you can pass the UserDefinedType like this, make sure you get all the properties you need, I suspect you'll get lot of null values for the non primitive parts.

Comment: The strange thing is that the user defined type does not contain fancy stuff.  It just contains primitive data types (strings).  The even stranger part to this problem is that this user defined type is passed to the web service more than the time that I am trying to do it, and the operation works just fine.  Strange, sounds like something that I am doing wrong.

Comment: @AndHeCodedIt how can you tell it's passed more times than you're trying? maybe the problem is with your debug technique?

Comment: There are two other methods in my web service that accept this user defined type.  They have existed for 6+ months without any issues.  When I call one of the 2 existing web methods and pass the user defined type the web service returns information successfully.  When I call my new web service method and pass the user defined type, I get no response from the web service.  Is that clearer?

Comment: @AndHeCodedIt - any chance some other parameter is the culprit? Maybe some code in the web method itself?

Comment: Not that I can find.  I have placed debug statements (our own logging string prints to a file) in the line of code directly after processing should enter the web method.  Instead of seeing the debug statement I should see from the server, I get an error on the client side telling me that it is "Unable to read from the Transport Connection"  It seems as if my client side is timing out because it can't "see" the web service method.  Keep in mind that my new method is an overload of a previous method that does work.  The only new piece is my new userDefinedType parameter.

Comment: @AndHeCodedIt - another idea... check the auto generated Reference.cs file when you have UserDefinedType  in place... do you see the type there? What happens when you F12 it? I'm trying to see maybe the problem is with VS while creating the reference..

Comment: When I hit F12 it finds the userDefinedType as it is generated in Reference.cs

Comment: OK, I see one major difference between the class as defined in source code and the class as it is defined in Reference.cs .  The variables in the Reference.cs class use data type string (lower case) however in the source code the userDefinedType expects the type String (uppercase).  Do you see this presenting a problem?

Comment: @AndHeCodedIt: Can't see how this can cause any problem. It's like int vs. Int32 - both are the same, int being "alias" to the true type Int32. Let me understand though, you have it working OK by now using the trick you posted? Or is something still wrong with the code?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, Yes.  I still have some time to figure out what the real problem is though.  I will repost when I figure it out.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard.  Please see my edit to my answer.  I was aghast at what I discovered to be the problem and quite upset that I spent so much time trying to figure out what the real problem was =(.  Thanks for all of your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible as long as your type is [serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx).

Comment: Does the type just need to be serializable or do I also need to serialize it before passing it to the WebMethod?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.  The same type is being passed in other functions that are calling the web service.  It was worth a try though. Thanks!

Comment: So, maybe by making the name shorter it was less than the maxContentLength in your webconfig. (I think that is the tag to look for). I know I had a webmethod failing intermittently, but I fixed it by changing the maxContentLength rather than the class name, either way would seem to get your total input string under the max length requirement.